# Wonder what the word "register" really is talking about in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> Members of the religion cannot register with the government officially. Despite this, members do not face significant persecution due to the separation of religion and state here.

I have my doubts around my perception of this word. There is an ambiguty.
Does it mean:

1. They can not put their religion on application forms to get a job and by leaving the space blank they can be addmitted to the governmentally jobs or governmentally run universities.
2. Even by not putting their religion on application forms they can not be accepted in governmentally run jobs or enter university.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume it means the government doesn't recognise it as a religion, or that the religion dictates you can't work for the government. Your two assumptions don't seem to relate to 'register' specifically, rather the whole sentence.

Comment: More context is necessary to understand this passage. Does the source give any examples of people or groups who *do* register with the government?

Comment: @phenry - No actully.

Comment: @user5036 - Is this the United States government?

Comment: No Turkey it is ............................

Comment: @phenry - No Turkey

Comment: I don't think this is really a question about English, but I've tried to give you an answer anyway.

Comment: @henry - It sounds like that it is not about English.  But when I read the text I cannot notice what it really saying. Because English is a foreign language for me and I don't leave in Turkey.  Thanks for your decent comments and answer.

Comment: @phenry  - It sounds like that it is not about English. But when I read the text I cannot notice what it really saying. Because English is a foreign language for me and I don't leave in Turkey. Thanks for your decent comments and answer. IJUST WONDER WHAT THE PART "THEY CANNOT REGISTER "IN THIS CONTEXT MEAN? EVEN I DO NOT KNOW WHAT REGISTER MEAN HERE.  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bah%C3%A1%27%C3%AD_Faith_in_Turkey

Comment: I think the OP has provided in the comments enough context to answer this question, and thus, the question shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've indicated that the government in question is the government of Turkey, which is strongly secular and has taken a number of steps to prevent certain religious groups from dominating public life and culture. I found [this](http://www.state.gov/j/drl/rls/irf/religiousfreedom/index.htm?dlid#wrapper) in a U.S. State Department report on religious freedom in Turkey:

> The constitution prohibits discrimination on religious grounds.... Although registration with the government is not mandatory for religious groups, unregistered religious groups cannot request legal recognition of places of worship, and holding religious services at a location not recognized as a place of worship is illegal.

Because registration is not mandatory, and because religious discrimination is prohibited, I conclude that the members' inability to register is not relevant to their prospects for employment.

Comment: It sounds like that it is not about English. But when I read the text I cannot notice what it really saying. Because English is a foreign language for me and I don't leave in Turkey. Thanks for your decent comments and answer. IJUST WONDER WHAT THE PART "THEY CANNOT REGISTER "IN THIS CONTEXT MEAN? EVEN I DO NOT KNOW WHAT REGISTER MEAN HERE. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bah%C3%A1%27%C3%AD_Faith_in_Turkey

Comment: You would have to ask someone with more knowledge of Turkey to be sure, but I would guess that it would be similar to registering to vote: you inform the government of your identity and what religion you belong to, using a formal, centralized process.

Comment: I think there's clearly enough context to say that it is the religious group which must 'register'--declare itself to the government so it may be placed on an official list (register) of recognized religious groups. See [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/register?q=register), **register** *verb* sense 1.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to answer this question some context is needed and fortunately user5036 provided this context in the comments.

The quoted text is coming from a Wikipedia entry on the [Bahá'í Faith in Turkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bah%C3%A1%27%C3%AD_Faith_in_Turkey).

> In the 21st century, many of the obstacles to the religion remain in place, as Bahá'ís cannot **register** with the government officially[<sup>[1]</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bah%C3%A1%27%C3%AD_Faith_in_Turkey#cite_note-regulation-1).

Wikipedia, always keen to provide citations, gives a link to the reference that motivated the statement above.

> Religious affiliation is listed on national identity cards, despite 1982 Constitutional Article 24 which provides that no one shall be compelled to reveal religious beliefs. A few religious groups, such as the Baha'i, are unable to state their religious affiliation on their cards because their religion is not included among the options. Despite a 2006 regulation allowing persons to leave the religion section of their identity cards blank or change the religious designation by written application, the Government continued to restrict applicants' choice of religion. Despite the regulation, applicants must choose Muslim, Christian, Jew, Hindu, Zoroastrian, Confucian, Taoist, Buddhist, Religionless, Other, or Unknown as their religious affiliation.
>
> ([U.S. State Department (2008-09-19). "International Religious Freedom Report 2008 - Turkey"](http://www.state.gov/j/drl/rls/irf/2008/108476.htm))

It is clear now, as StoneyB correctly guessed, that ["register"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/register?q=register) in this case means:

> "Enter one’s name and other details on an official list or directory"

**SHORT ANSWER**

Hence, to answer your question, we can now say that the sentence *"the Bahá'ís cannot register with the government officially"* means that in Turkey the members of the Bahá'í faith cannot register/declare in their identity cards that they profess the Bahá'í religion.